# Express cookie on server not equal to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, cookies

I'm currently building a simple web app with node.js, express and mongodb. As far as I got it works fine, except when I try to use cookies via express.
The problem is that I'm sending an ID over express by using

```
res.cookie("id", data.id);
```

On the server side I'm recieving the right ID, for example `587cb2d9da936f1f758fa241`
which is the one express sends.
But when I try to log out the id on the browser side I'm getting

```
id=j%3A%22587cb2d9da936f1f758fa241%22
```

As you can see the ID is still in there, but something weird happened to the data on the way to the client. Am I missing something or is that a normal thing I have to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is j:"587cb2d9da936f1f758fa241". Quotes and colon got URL Encoded when passed over the network 
Maybe server side stores the data with a j key and URL Encode it before sending